# Whitelisting OpenWRT servers on my gateway

Tags: ip, ip-address, openwrt, gateway, whitelist

I am looking to whitelist the OpenWRT IP's on my gateway for when software updates occur. Does anyone know of any resources for the IP range they use for software updates?

Comment: What do you mean by whitelisting an IP? are you talking about the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

The packages come from downloads.openwrt.org by default. They have multiple mirrors if you have selected one. But as you can see it is domain based, not IP based. So the underlying IP could change at any time.

Reference: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/additional-software/opkg?s[]=get&s[]=packages